# Why does the scanf not stop after typing in something and pressing enter

Tags: c

The code just keeps accepting input and doesn't go on to the if logic and i have no idea why

```
    while (1){

    // get command
    char cmd[6];
    scanf("%s", cmd);

    if (cmd == "exit"){
        return 0;
    } else if(cmd == "task\n"){
        taskHandler();
    } else if(cmd == "event"){
        eventHandler();
    } else if(cmd == "show"){
        showItems();
    }
}
```

Comment: String compare doesn't work the way you think it does. Try looking up and update your comparisons.

Comment: The string returned by `%s` cannot *ever* contain whitespace, hence it will never match your `"task\n"` with a newline either.

Answer (score 2):

In C you can't use `==` to compare strings, as that would compare the value of the *pointer*, i.e. the location in memory that has the string data. If you want to compare the actual data, you have to use `strcmp`, i.e:

```
if(cmd == "exit") {
  ...
}
```

should be

```
if(strcmp(cmd, "exit") == 0) {
  ...
}
```

`int strcmp(const char* str0, const char* str1)` returns whether `str1` is lexicographically less than, equal to, or greater than (`-1`, `0`, and `1` respectively), so if it returns `0`, then `str0` and `str1` are equal.

I'd also use `break` instead of the `return 0` and move the `return 0` to outside of the `while(1)` loop.

Answer (score 0):

In c language you can't use == operator to compare two string. Instead you should use strcmp function to compare two string. See this [link](https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/string_h/strcmp.php).